# Is there a prohibition for shaving ones mustache with a blade?

Tags: halacha, shaving

Reason why question is brought up in the first place :

Halacha : one may not take a blade to their face when shaving in 5 specific places.

Question :

There is no mention of a prohibition towards shaving the mustache. Are we to assume that we can shave it with a blade?

Comment: Assuming your premise of 5 specific places is correct (source?), and assuming the mustache is not one of those places (source?) can you explain why you would think the prohibition might apply to it?